# Android connects to VPN

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, vpn

To debug a web application, I used a web debugging proxy. And I found that android devices keep connecting to a VPN with the address:

https://scss-prod-ew1-notif-8.adobesc.com:443

Does anyone have an idea what is this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a service from Adobe.

[WhoIs: Adobe](https://who.is/whois/adobesc.com)

Other Domain siblings they use:

```
scss-prod-an1-notif-8.adobesc.com
scss-prod-an1-notif-7.adobesc.com
scss-prod-ue1-notif-5.adobesc.com
scss-prod-ue1-notif-11.adobesc.com
scss-prod-an1-notif-2.adobesc.com
scss-prod-an1-notif-4.adobesc.com
scss-prod-an1-notif-3.adobesc.com
scss-prod-an1-notif-1.adobesc.com
scss-prod-an1-notif-5.adobesc.com
scss-prod-ue1-notif-10.adobesc.com
```